# Customising terminal environment

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, bashrc

I want to customise the command prompt. I've added:

```
 PS1='\[\e[1;30m\][\[\e[1;34m\]\u@\h \[\e[0;36m\]\A\[\e[1;30m\]]\[\e[1;37m\]~\W\[\e[0;37m\] \$ \e[0;100m'
```

to `~/.bashrc`. It is all good except that not the **entire terminal background is black** but only the background blocks behind the command input/output (sorry for privacy reasons, I can't upload a screen shot but code works in terminal).

I have tried moving the `\e[0;100m` around but nothing was successful.

I have seen a couple of relevant questions on this topic but I still seem to be unable fix my problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the background color of your terminal using `$PS1` is not possible (AFAIK) as using ANSI escape sequence will only affect your prompt and what you can type after the prompt if an ANSI code is still active, nothing more.

If I were you I'd change my `$PS1` to be just:

```
PS1='\[\e[1;30m\][\[\e[1;34m\]\u@\h \[\e[0;36m\]\A\[\e[1;30m\]]\[\e[1;37m\]~\W\[\e[0;37m\] \$'
```

And change the background color of your gnome-terminal in the profile preferences, select the "White on Black" built-in scheme:

[image]

The result:

[image]